# Sending a 2D array to calculate the total and show the result in the function

Tags: c

I want to find the size of the array, separated by another function

I tried sending the information. But it does not show results correctly

```
int main()
{
int amount[2];
int price[2][4];
int total[4];

getData(amount,price,total);
getSizeOfArray(amount,price,total);

}
void getData(int amount[2],int price[2][4],int total[2])
{
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    printf("+++Department %d+++\n\n",i+1);
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        printf("Costomer %d\n",j+1);
        printf("Enter amount : ");
        scanf("%d",&amount[i]);
        printf("Enter price : ");
        scanf("%d",&price[i][j]);

        total[j]=amount[i]*price[i][j];
    }
    printf("\n=================\n");

}
}

void getSizeOfArray(int amount[2],int price[2][4],int total[2])
{

}
```

Comment: "_But it does not show results correctly_" How exactly does it not show the results? Please post the current output and the expected output along with a [mcve]. Also, you have `int total[2]` instead of `int total[4]`

Comment: "But it does not show results correctly" Well, I don't see any code in `getSizeOfArray` and I don't see any `printf` of values. Did you post the code correctly?

Comment: Why do you read `amount` in the inner loop? You keep overwrinting the same variable

Comment: Why is `total` sometimes 2 and sometimes 4?

Comment: "I want to find the size of the array ...", well... It's a bit unclear if you actually mean the **size of array** or it's some sum of elements you are looking for. If it **is the size**, the answer is that you can't. Once you pass an array to a function there is no way to find the original array size. You have to pass the size as an argument (or use a sentinel).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the amount array size:

```
int getSizeOfArray(int* amount)
{
    return (sizeof(amount) / sizeof(int));
}
```

it will return 2

and if you want to get the price array size:

```
int * getSizeOfArray(int** price)
{
    int size[2];
    size[1] = (sizeof(price[0]) / sizeof(int));
    size[0] = (sizeof(price) / sizeof(int)) / size[1];
    return size;
}
```

it will return an array:

size[0]: 2

size[1]: 4